# New Matrix Command

Tags: matrices

I've been using matrices in Latex for while but have found them somewhat tedious to write. Is it possible to create a new command \nmatrix (for instance) in latex that allows matrices to be written in the following form:

```
\nmatrix{1,2;3,4}
```

And would yield the following matrix:

[image: Example Matrix]

I know you could define something like

```
\newcommand{\nmatrix}[4]{$ \begin{bmatrix} #1 & #2 \\ #3 & #4\\\end{bmatrix} $}
```

however this takes effort to write and ideally I'd like to be able to write any m by m matrix using the command \nmatrix by changing the number of inputs. Eg \nmatrix{1,2,3;4,5,6} would then yield a 2 by 3 matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tailor made for `tabstackengine`, which already has such a macro (and others).

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackEOL{;}% row separator
\setstackTAB{,}% column separator
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}% inter-column gap
\setstackgap{L}{1.0\normalbaselineskip}% inter-row baselineskip
\let\nmatrix\bracketMatrixstack
\begin{document}
\[
\nmatrix{1,2,3;4,5,6}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

An optional argument exists to set the column alignment as `l`, `c`, or `r`.

It also has a `\fixTABwidth{<T or F>}` macro to set all columns to the same width (or not), shown before and after:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I was wondering though, is there any way to do this with round brackets instead of square brackets? Thanks!

Comment: @SamDavenport Sure. `\parenMatrixstack`.  There is also `\braceMatrixstack`, `\vertMatrixstack`, and simply `\Matrixstack`.  See `tabstackengine` documentation at http://ctan.org/pkg/tabstackengine