# Vertical alignment problems with bracketMatrixstack from tabstackengine

Tags: vertical-alignment, matrices, alignment, stackengine

I came across this pretty nifty command to easily create matrices, that I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/370625/new-matrix-command).

However, when I tried to use it with `\vdots` and `\ddots`, I ran into some vertical alignment issues. Here is the code I tried:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\setstackEOL{;}% row separator
\setstackTAB{,}% column separator
\setstacktabbedgap{1ex}% inter-column gap
\setstackgap{L}{1.0\normalbaselineskip}% inter-row baselineskip
\let\nmatrix\bracketMatrixstack
\begin{document}
\[
\nmatrix{a_{11}, \dots, a_{1n}; \vdots, \ddots, \vdots; a_{m1}, \dots, a_{mn}}
\]
\end{document}
```

And this is what the output looks like:

[image]

I was wondering if there was a way to center-align the middle row vertically.

Comment: You should have a look at `nicematrix`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why going the hard way.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & \dots  & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & \dots  & a_{mn}
\end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]